# How to run a Windows Form in a C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and I have just designed a simple Form that captures some user input text and displays it to the screen.  However, I don't know how to include this Form in a C# application.  The code in the Form1.cs file is obviously incomplete -- ie, it does not contain any formatting data.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the normal WIndows Forms application template, Form1 will automatically load when you run.

If not, I recommend building a template program, and looking at Program.cs - it shows the typically boilerplate code used to launch the "main" form and start the application properly.

Comment: I took a look in Program.cs and everything appears to be there.  Now I am wondering how to launch this program either by double clicking on an icon or using the command line.

Comment: @Kevin It should make an exe file for you - just run that.  If you're working in Visual Studio, hit the Run button to start debugging...

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Actually I just found it.  Thanks for your help.